# controlling heating element using microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, solid-state-relay

I have a 3000 Watt, 240 VAC heating element. (This is the heating element in a commercial espresso machine.) I want to use a micro controller to turn power to machine on and off. it has a pressure controlled relay in it now that will control the heating element when powered as well. I plan to use two CMRD2435 to do this. I included a datasheet here. It seems like I can just use this as they are, but one blew on me the other day. Did I do something wrong? It worked for months without issue.

http://www.crydom.com/en/Products/Catalog/c_mr24.pdf

Comment: As a follow-up. My power source is two phase which is why i used two relays. The second SSR was faulty. I bought them used in a set of four and the replacement has been working perfectly ever since.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using two of the SSR modules (solid state relays)? 3000 Watts supplied from 240V RMS is about a load of about 12.5 Amps RMS. This should be an easy load for the CMRD2435 to handle.

If you were paralleling two SSRs to share a larger load than either one was rated for then it is feasible that they would not turn on and off at the same time and thus one unit could end up being overloaded whilst it was momentarily bearing the brunt of the load.

It could be that the pressure relay is pulsing on and off rapidly when the SSR is on. If the load has an inductive component to it this can generate huge high voltage spikes that are a death nail for an SSR. Your SSR is rated for a peak of 600V peak transient. An inductive load could be generating spikes well over that level.

You should check your setup for the presence of spikes using an oscilloscope. If large spikes are present you will have to look at adding MOV type clamp components and possibly some R/C snubber circuits across the the heater load to suppress the large spikes.

Comment: I used two because the power source is 220V each leg of the source is 120 V. How can I find information about using an oscilloscope to do that test? I am guessing that is one of the common tests I might find in a book on using oscilloscopes right? In a relay the inductive load comes fro the contacts disconnecting or the magnet in the coil turning off? My pressure state is completely mechanical. I am guessing the only way to find out it to test it right?

Comment: That's a whole pile of assumptions/misconceptions in one comment. Can you go back, edit your question to specify a LOT more detail about what's going on? Is this 220v single-phase or what?

Comment: With my limited level of knowledge i would be guessing, but i believe its 220V two-phase, because i am sure each leg is 120v by itself. is that the what you mean?